# Caffeine AsyncLoadingCache and thundering herd

Tags: caffeine

Does .get() on a Caffeine AsyncLoadingCache prevent concurrent loads, by delaying subsequent threads which are calling .get() until the first one completes? Or that it can be configured to return a stale value while a self-populating load request is occurring?

This is so that a thundering herd can be prevented by using the cache.

I am seeing behavior which indicates that the thundering herd is not handled even though I am using a cache.

I create the cache like so:

```
val queryResponseCache: AsyncLoadingCache<Request, Response> = Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .recordStats()
            .buildAsync(queryLoader)
```

And use it in conjunction with a L2 cache in redis like so (kotlin elvis operator):

```
queryResponseCache.getIfPresent(key) ?: fetchFromRedis(key) ?: queryResponseCache.get(key)
```

I understand that getIfPresent is concurrent, but the subsequent calls  which end up calling fetchFromRedis() / get() seem to have problems. I guess moving the `fetchFromRedis` into the `asyncLoad()` function might be better for load tolerance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cache stampede is supported when you load through the cache. In your example using `getIfPresent` and loading the value, then I assume you put it into the cache explicitly inside of `fetchFromRedis`. Either way, you are ensuring a racy get-load-put due to bypassing the cache except when absent in Redis.

If you move the logic into `asyncLoad`, as you surmised, it would let the cache handle the stampede. The redis lookup, db query, and storing back into redis can all be performed as a chain of asynchronous tasks where the final future is returned to `asyncLoad`. Then the cache will compute the future once and return it to all subsequent calls until the entry is evicted.